# Spring JPA data not inserting into the order in which it posted

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I don't know wheather anyone had this type of issue before or not! So but basically when i do save object it insert random order but not actual order in which i am sending it from POST api via UI. Below is my json object which i am sending to spring jpa for insertion,

```
{"expense":"wwww","amounts":[{"amount":"23","version":0},{"amount":"12","version":0},{"amount":"27","version":0},{"amount":"22","version":0},{"amount":"22","version":0},{"amount":"1111","version":0}],"version":0}
```

and this amounts are the `Set<expense> amounts` into my parent object as @manytomany relationship. And data insert into the random order but it should have insert the order which it sent from, correct me if i am wrong anywhere. In database it saves like 22,12,22,1111,,23,27 which is random.

Comment: can you debug in what order items are received on server, otherwise take a look at `JsonPropertyOrder`

Comment: @silentsudo after debuging on server side seems like order gets changed.

Comment: did you try `@JsonPropertyOrder` on `amounts` field

Comment: tried this way@JsonPropertyOrder({"amount"}) but still its inserting into random order!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java the `Set` interface doesn't guarantee any order. You can use a `SortedSet` for your mapping, or use a `List`. Both can be ordered and will preserve the one received from some JSON.

Some documentation :

[Set Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html)

[SortedSet Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html)

Comment: This impact entire code because that class used almost everywhere.. unfortunately i cannot do that.